# @media screen and (min-width: 1280px){ does not work even though my resolution is 1920*1080

Tags: html, css

The Navigation menu items are not showing for 1920 * 1080

I set display = none for all device widths except >1280

```
 `@media only screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 260px) {

  header .navigation {
  display: none;
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: 260px) and (max-width: 350px) {

  header .navigation {
  display: none;
  }



 @media only screen and (min-width: 370px) and (max-width: 500px) {
  header .navigation {
 display: none;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
header .navigation {
display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 350px) and (max-width: 370px) {

header .navigation {
display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1280px){

header .navigation{

height:3em;
position: relative;
background:  dark orange ;
width:98em;
top:50;
left:-12em;
font-size:30px;
font-color: dark orange;
font-family: Meow Script;
padding:20px;
}


header .navigation .navigation-items a{

 font-family: Meow Script;
  position: relative;
  background: dark red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 500;
  width:100px;
  font-size:20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 15px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  left :15em;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  border-radius:150px;
  font-family: Meow Script;
  }

  header .navigation .navigation-items a span{
  border-radius:50px;
  width:100px;
  font-family: Meow Script;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  }

  header .navigation .navigation-items a:before{
   content: '';
   position: absolute; 
   font-family: Meow Script;
   width: 0;
   height: 3px;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   transition: 0.3s ease;
  }

  header .navigation .navigation-items a:hover:before{
  width: 100%;
  }
  }`

  if I use the same in a different CSS file without media queries I am able to see the navigation menus in my Laptop 1920*  1080 resolution.
```

[Navigation menus showing when CSS used without media Query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1B8A.png)[Navigation menu not showing when CSS used with media Query for 1920*1080 Laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NubZK.png)

I tried to write media queries such that Navigation menu shows only >1280 px width and not for smaller screen width like mobile and Laptop.

I made display = none for all device widths <1280px.

But the navigation menu is not displaying for 1920*1080 as

well (>1280px width)

Comment: Start mobile first in your media queries, and build up from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `only` on the last `mediaQuery`.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px){
```

Should be

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px){
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, I tried adding only as well but did not succeed. One more thing I observed when I opened developer tools is my device shows as 1274*1080  instead of 1920*1080             and hence its taking another media query.    I checked Setting   ---->   display of my Laptop it shows 1920*1080

Comment: Well, that's probably your problem. This might shed some light: https://superuser.com/q/762956

Comment: Thanks Richard, Your answer solved the problem, Screen resolution shows as 1280*720 ,probably browser resolution using the article link that you shared. Let me go through in detail How to make my screen resolution of browser same as that of Windows settings  i.e 1920*1080 and Test.

Comment: Also if there is anything in particular I have to take care for responsiveness apart from writing Media Queries and checking that everything is fine for all the devices present in Developer tools Emulator.

Comment: That's most of it. If everything works fine on each device, you're good. You can also check under-the-surface problems, like having huge images that are getting displayed small, but still taking up lots of bandwidth.

Comment: yes right, Image bandwidth has to be checked and Background video has to be disabled as well in my case. Thanks Richard for your answer. (uday@earlytester)

Answer (score 0):

Start fixing some errors in your CSS, if you don't know what fix try using an online validator, like this:

https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Maybe the problem is not properly on the media queries but in the output generated by other rules.

Hint about media queries: put all your CSS outside the media Queries and use them only to change the desired features. Pay attention to the order of the media queries, sometime a statement overwrite the one before.

Try this CSS:

```
header .navigation {
    display: none;
}
header .navigation {
    height: 3em;
    position: relative;
    background: darkorange;
    width: 98em;
    /* top:50;*/ /* this make the object disappear */
    /* left:-12em;*/ /* this make youtr object disappear */
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Meow Script;
    padding: 20px;
}
header .navigation .navigation-items a {
    font-family: Meow Script;
    position: relative;
    background: darkred;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 500;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 15px;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
    left : 15em;
    padding: 15px 40px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    font-family: Meow Script;
}
header .navigation .navigation-items a span {
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    font-family: Meow Script;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
header .navigation .navigation-items a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Meow Script;
    width: 0;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: 0.3s ease;
}
header .navigation .navigation-items a:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
header .navigation {
    display: block;
}
}
```

Working Codepen: https://codepen.io/Davevvave/pen/poZrwZE

Comment: Thanks vvave The problem was with the Screen resolution.I checked online resolution checker, It shows browser resolution as 1280*720 instead of 1920*1080 which is my Laptop resolution(uday@earlytester)